# Image not showing on localhost after deploying on github

Tags: reactjs, image, github, localhost, github-pages

my React project is not showing images on localhost after deploying it on GitHub. It working and showing images on github but when i run the same react project on my localhost it can't show images.

i changed the images path such as "../images/image.jpg" or "/images/image.jpg", but it can't working

Answer (score 0):

If you have stored your images in the public folder in this manner

```
node_modules
public
├── images
│   ├── image.jpg
├── index.html
src
```

then in order to access the image.jpg use

```
<img src="./images/image.jpg" />
```

If you have stored image in this manner

```
node_modules
public
├── index.html
src
├── images
│  ├── image.jpg
├── App.js
```

then inorder to access it into the file use

```
import SampleImage from "./images/image.jpg"

export default function App(){
  return(
    <img src={SampleImage} />
  )
}
```

Comment: I try it but it can't work. It work well before deploying on GitHub, after deployed on GitHub and then run on localhost it can't show images on localhost.